# I'm trying to make the date to be concise, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying many methods to solve this data, but it can't work. `strip()` and `replace()` methods look like in the picture one, it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
 `  improt requests
    from lxml import html,etree
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time


    file_name = 'dubanxinlixue.json'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url_string = []
    name_data, price_data = [], []
    jd_goods_data = {}
    page = 0
    while True:

        url = 'https://book.douban.com/tag/%E5%BF%83%E7%90%86%E5%AD%A6?start={page}&type=S'.format(page=page)
        url_string.append(url)
        page += 20
        if page > 980:
            break

    for i in url_string:
        driver.get(i)
        base_html = driver.page_source
        selctor = etree.HTML(base_html)
        j = 1
        for j in range(20):
            j += 1

            name = '//*[@id="subject_list"]/ul/li[%d]/div[2]/h2/a[1]/@title'%(j)
            get_name =selctor.xpath(name)[0]
            describe = '//*[@id="subject_list"]/ul/li[%d]/div[2]/div[1]/text()'%(j)
        get_describe = selctor.xpath(describe)[0]

        get_describe.string.strip()
        print(get_describe)`

the get_describe looks like this ,[the result of get_describe][1]
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. Describe the desired output, describe how it works now in your question.

Comment: Can you clearify the question?

Comment: thank for Gonczor and Metareven help,but i find out the error,very thank you help

Comment: i was so inattention that forgot the variable,the code i must change like this new_get_describe = get_describe.strip()
 print(new_get_describe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_get_describe = get_describe.strip()
print(new_get_describe)
```